# SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.MulticastThread] but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to upgrade the Hazelcast from 2.x to 3.3, but when I start up the server after changing all  the related classes, this error occurs.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.MulticastThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Dose anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Did you hot replace the web application or did you do a cold boot of Tomcat?

Comment: Most likely your web application is not closing the hazelcast context which it unloads.

Comment: I stop the tomcat first then start it again. How should I do unloading the hazelcast context?

Comment: It's resolved and I don't know why, maybe it's because it's not closed as Perter said. Thank you all.